# django deleteview NoReverseMatch at

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django.
I keep receiving NoReverseMatch  when building an app. Was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong.

The app has scenarios, each scenario has associated emailss.  When I click on a scenario the app displays the emails associated to the scenario, allowing the user to then delete/edit each of the associated email.

When I try delete an email I receive a NoReverseMatch if I have the success_url set to the email:index which generated the list of emails for that scenario. If I change success_url to the main screen(scenarios:index) it works however this is not ideal having the user go to the main screen listing the scenarios on each deletion.

Here are my url patterns for the email datasource

```
# emails
# /scenarios/<scenarioid>/email
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/email/$', views.EmailListView.as_view(), name='email-index'),
# /scenarios/12/email/<emailid>/delete
url(r'^([0-9]+)/email/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.EmailDelete.as_view(), name='email-delete'),
```

Here's my views file:

```
class EmailDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Email
    success_url = reverse_lazy('scenarios:email-index')

class EmailListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Email
    template_name = 'scenarios/emailindex.html'
    context_object_name = 'scenario_emails'
    print "in email list view"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Email.objects.filter(scenario=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Here's the template:

```
<td><form action="{% url 'scenarios:email-delete' email.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`email-delete` URL has two capture groups - one non-named `([0-9]+)` and one named `(?P<pk>[0-9]+)`, but in the `url` tag you pass only positional argument - `email.id`. You must either remove the first group from url pattern or pass two arguments to `url` tag. Something like this `{% url 'scenarios:email-delete' scenario.id pk=email.id %}`.

Comment: Thanks Sergey!

Tried this but it didnt seem to work. Got an error saying you cannot mix kwarg with args. 
` url(r'^(?P<scenario_id>[0-9]+)/email/(?P<email_id>[0-9+)/$'' `

I made both patterns in the URL named groups and use 
` {% url 'scenarios:email-delete' scenario_id=email.scenario.pk email_id=email.id %}. `


I am not receiving a NoReserve match error, however it is not deleting the email I selected.. hopefully I am getting close..